# How to Properly Define This Zsh Function

Tags: zsh, zshrc

when I run `kotlinc hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar`, things work perfectly...

but if I run `ktcompile hello.kt hello.jar`

where `ktcompile` is defined like so in my zshrc:

```
function ktcompile () {
    kotlinc $1 -include-runtime -d $2
}
```

I get an error: `error: source file or directory not found: hello.jar`

What's the difference here between typing it out in the command line versus using the zsh function? It still gives me the same error when I try to use absolute paths like:

```
function ktcompile () {
    kotlinc '$PWD/$1' -include-runtime -d '$PWD/$2'
}
```

Comment: Your second attempt needs to use double quotes, not single quotes, to allow `$PWD` to be expanded. It shouldn't be necessary, though: are you sure you are running `ktcompile` with the same working directory as the original command?

Comment: yes I am using the same directory for both

Comment: I can confirm that the double quotes solve the issue. Feel free to add a proper answer and I'll select it.

Comment: I just see that the `()` after the function name are unnecessary, but they don't harm and your first version looks perfectly fine. You can verify it by running it using `set -x`. The second version with single quotes is garbage, of course. Are you sure that you are running the correct `ktcompile`, and that you really are in Zsh? Do a `echo $ZSH_VERSION`, a  and a `type -f ktcompile` to verify this.